# Java NumberFormat rounding mode, why half up format 1.015 to 1.01 not to 1.02

Tags: java, number-formatting

## Java Code

```
@Test
void a() {
    NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.CHINA);
    format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    format.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance(Locale.CHINA));
    for (RoundingMode mode : RoundingMode.values()) {
        if(mode == RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY) continue;
        format.setRoundingMode(mode);
        System.out.println("Rounding mode: " + mode);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("\t format 1.014 is " + format.format(1.014));
        System.out.println("\t format 1.015 is " + format.format(1.015));
        System.out.println("\t format 1.016 is " + format.format(1.016));
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

## The result:

### Rounding mode: UP

```
 format 1.014 is 1.02
 format 1.015 is 1.02
 format 1.016 is 1.02
```

### Rounding mode: DOWN

```
 format 1.014 is 1.01
 format 1.015 is 1.01
 format 1.016 is 1.01
```

### Rounding mode: CEILING

```
 format 1.014 is 1.02
 format 1.015 is 1.02
 format 1.016 is 1.02
```

### Rounding mode: FLOOR

```
 format 1.014 is 1.01
 format 1.015 is 1.01
 format 1.016 is 1.01
```

### Rounding mode: HALF_UP

```
 format 1.014 is 1.01
 format 1.015 is 1.01
 format 1.016 is 1.02
```

### Rounding mode: HALF_DOWN

```
 format 1.014 is 1.01
 format 1.015 is 1.01
 format 1.016 is 1.02
```

### Rounding mode: HALF_EVEN

```
 format 1.014 is 1.01
 format 1.015 is 1.01
 format 1.016 is 1.02
```

Process finished with exit code 0

## So, does there have a simple way to make 1.015 formatted to 1.02?(JDK 12, JDK 8)

Answer (score 4):

That is because 1.015 is actually
`1.0149999999999999023003738329862244427204132080078125`

A solution using BigDecimal works for a String

```
BigDecimal db = new BigDecimal("1.015");
db = db.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);`
```

Answer (score -1):

Using Rounding mode: CEILING (to round up)

```
public static Double roundUp(double n, int decimalPlace) {
    BigDecimal instance = new BigDecimal(Double.toString(n));
    return instance.setScale(decimalPlace, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue();
}
```

Example : `roundUp(1.014, 2)` --> `1.02`